# In android is it possible to open the phone contacts list using preferences

Tags: android

I am new in android development, Please help me to solve this, I want to know can I open the phone contacts list using preferences.
Please tell me which preference I have to use for this I tried it with the list preferences but not be able to solve this.Please suggest me what is best approach to solve this.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you want to add a preference to pick a contact from the phone contact list. There is no direct support for it, i.e. there is no `ContactPreference`. You could create your own preference by extending `DialogPreference`. Calling the standard `PICK_CONTACT` action may help.

Answer (score 0):

hmm yes,

this is from the sample api docs,

```
 public class List3 extends ListActivity {

         @Override
         protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
             super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

             // Get a cursor with all phones
             Cursor c = getContentResolver().query(Phones.CONTENT_URI,
     null, null, null, null);
             startManagingCursor(c);

             // Map Cursor columns to views defined in
     simple_list_item_2.xml
             ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, c, 
                             new String[] { Phones.NAME, Phones.NUMBER }, 
                             new int[] { android.R.id.text1,
     android.R.id.text2 });
             setListAdapter(adapter);
         }   
 }
```